# Simulation using python and graphics.py image

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simulator. ([referring to John Zelle's graphics.py](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html))
Basically, my object will make use of `graphics.py` to display the object as a circle. Then, using the `.move` method in the class in `graphics.py`, the object will move in the x direction and y direction. If the object is currently drawn, the circle is adjusted to the new position.

Moving just one object can easily be done with the following codes:

```
win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
c.draw(win)
    for i in range(40):       
      c.move(30, 0) #speed=30
      time.sleep(1)
win.close()
```

However, I want the program to display multiple circles at once that moves at different speed. I've created a Circle object class which takes speed as an input, and a list with 3 Circle objects in it

```
circle = []
circle1 = Car(40)
circle2= Car(50)
circle3 = Car(60)
```

In summary, my question is, how do make use of this list such that I am able to display and move multiple circles in one window at once using the methods available in `graphics.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all depends on how you create your `Car` class, but nothing stops you from using the same code to move multiple circles in the same refresh cycle, e.g.:

```
win = GraphWin("My Circle", 1024, 400)

speeds = [40, 50, 60]  # we'll create a circle for each 'speed'
circles = []  # hold our circles
for speed in speeds:
    c = Circle(Point(50, speed), 10)  # use speed as y position, too
    c.draw(win)  # add it to the window
    circles.append((c, speed))  # add it to our circle list as (circle, speed) pair

for i in range(40):  # main animation loop
    for circle in circles:  # loop through the circles list
        circle[0].move(circle[1], 0)  # move the circle on the x axis by the defined speed
    time.sleep(1)  # wait a second...

win.close()
```

Of course, if you're already going to use classes, you might as well implement `move()` in it so your `Car` instances can remember their `speed` and then just apply it when you call `move()` on them in a loop.

Comment: pardon what do you mean by this line of codes? `circle[0].move(circle[1], 0)` i'm rather confused because as far as i am aware, circle[0] means entering the list at index 0, where the move method is applied on to it with its speed being circle[1]?

Comment: @KimSuYu - there was a typo in the code (misplaced circle and speed), even the comment had it right. I've updated the code.